# How do I add Addin to the MS Project?

Tags: ms-project

MS Project 2016 x64

I created an add-in in Visual Studio.
When debugging, it works.

How can I add Addin to the MS Project so that it works without Visual Studio?
[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vDecv.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It shall be published - please use project properties => Publish tab for that - to get setup.exe and .vsto manifest file generated. Then please install it.